# referencing labels from other files

Tags: cross-referencing, external-files

Sometimes I want to refer (using `\ref`) a `\label` from some other tex file. What is the right way to do it?

(It's, of course, possible to `\include` all files in one and then use `\includeonly` — but it breaks e.g. page and section numbering.)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

https://texfaq.org/FAQ-extref

> ### Referring to labels in other documents
>
> When producing a set of inter-related documents, you’ll often want to
> refer to labels in another document of the set; but LaTeX, of its own
> accord, doesn’t permit this.
>
> So the package `xr` was written: if you say
>
> ```
> \usepackage{xr}
> \externaldocument{volume1}
> ```
>
> will load all the references from volume1 into your present document.
>
> (...)

Comment: The package looks for the `aux` file, so it does not work in all settings and, more importantly, without a full document. (Which is fair, but noteworthy for unwary readers.)

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: Could you please explain how I an do the reverse at the same time? For instance, if I want to call a reference from the the 'present document' into the the 'volume1'?