# LaTeX; Refer in one document-class to chapters in another document-class

Tags: cross-referencing, document-classes, external-files, pdfpages

I want to include an article (with documentclass: `IEEEtran`)  into a report (with another, company specific, documentclass). I want to refer in the article (myarticle.pdf) to the ten appendices of the report. 
I tried it with  include pdf:

```
\documentclass{Report}  
\usepackage{pdfpages}  
\begin{document}   
Report  
includepdf{myarticle.pdf}%refer in this article to ~\ref{app:req}  
\appendix  
\chapter{Requirements}% The first appendix  
\label{app:req}  
\end{document}
```

The problem is that with `pdfpages` the article can not refer to the appendices of the report.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Take a look at the `xr` package, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3060/586

Comment: Great! That was exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Good, we'll close this as a duplicate then.