# Refer to specific place in reference

Tags: cross-referencing

What is the `revtex` standard (or commonly accepted practice)  to refer to an equation/table/figure/section in an external source?  (i.e. when I don't know the `\label`, therefore cannot use `\ref`).  For example if I want to point the reader to a specific section, say 1.2.3,  of an article that is in my bibliography, I would currently write ... in [section 1.2.3] `\cite{ref9}`...is it `\cite[Section (1.2.3)]{ref9}`  as suggested below?  (even though there is no `\label` for the section).  And is it the same for equation/table/figure?     Thanks

Comment: This is very similar in nature to [How to cite chapter in book?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2515/5764) You can use `\cite[Section~5]{foo}`, or `\cite[Equation (1.2)]{bar}`...

Comment: In case you want to use labels in another file, this is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3060/referencing-labels-from-other-files.

Comment: Welcome! Can you post a small, compilable document showing what you want? Right now, people obviously aren't at all clear what you need and an example is the best way to clarify your question.

Comment: Fair enough, and I've learned a bit in since.  The Reference articles are authored by other people, so I have no control over any tags within them - and therefore I now think I cannot \ref to them.   

Instead may I ask what the text standards are for pointing to a section within someone else's article?  I have, for example, written:

...[section 9.9.9] \cite {xxx} shows a good example of .....is that acceptable practice where one can't use \ref ?

Similarly what would the text only standards be for 'pointing' to other articles Tables, equations and figures?

Comment: @user1979205 Please edit your question (instead of adding comments) and reformulate it in such a way that visitors to this site can easily understand what you want.  People usually don't read all of the comments before they decide whether they can help you.  See also this page: http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour